# Doctrine nested set vs adjacency list

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I need to display a tree of categories by levels (all tree elements on each level).

```
Root
Cat1 (parent_id) Cat2 (parent_id) ...
Subcat1 (parent_id) Subcat2 (parent_id) Subcat3 (parent_id) ...
```

I tried to implement it with Nested Set structure, but I ran into a problem: no easy way to get the parent's node id (without a separate query to the database). Should I use Adjacency list instead?

The goal is to make the display as fast as possible, ideally with one query to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this article about Nested Set vs Adjacency List](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). You'll see that Nested Set makes the queries faaaaar easier to write.
Also read this § about [the nested set hierarchy hydration method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/data-hydrators#core-hydration-methods%3anested-set-record-hierarchy), and you'll figure out how to get several doctrine objects in a hierarchical form **with a single query**.